# Is there an image processing function to get a skeleton of a binary image in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, morphological-analysis

The objective of skeletonization is to represent a binary image with a minimum set of pixels. The skeleton must account for geometrical properties of the form and retain associative relationships.

My question here is how can I get a skeleton from binary image?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One approach is to use [BWMORPH](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/bwmorph.html).

```
%# assume your binary image is called binImg
skeleton = bwmorph(binImg,'skel',inf);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Medial Axis Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medial_axis) sounds like what you are looking for.